# Check if the parameter of a shell command exists

Tags: shell, parameters

In my program, I have to check whether a command given as a input by a user exists or not and if it exists, program needs to check if the parameters of that command are correct.

For example:

- `ls` ( is correct)
- `-al` (is correct)
- do the watch

and if I do this:

- `ls` (is correct)
- `-kala` (not correct)
- don't do the watch.

How I can do this? Here is my script:

```
while true
do
echo "Insert the command"
read comm
if [ "$(type -t $comm)" != "" ]; then
    echo "Insert the parameters of the command ";
    read par;
    echo "Insert the time of watch";
    read time;
    if [ $t -le 0 ]; then
        echo "Value not correct";
    else     
        clear;
        while true
        do
            echo "$comm"
            date
            echo ""
            $comm $par
            sleep $((time))
            clear
       done
    fi;
    else
        echo "Command not found, retry.";
        echo "";
    fi
done
```

Comment: what do you mean by "do the watch"?

Comment: If you want to check that the command is valid, try it.  If it is invalid, the command will fail and (usually) emit a nice error message that is far more accurate than any error message your script might hope to construct.

Comment: Watch is a function that every 2 seconds repeat a command (for exemple watch ls -al ) . Here I created my watch that allow the user to decide the number of seconds. The only problem is that if I lunch a command with wrong parameters, every n seconds it print the error. I want to stop the process if the command , the time or the parameters are incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the command invocation with this:

```
if ! $comm $par; then
    exit 1
fi
```

to make it stop after an error. Also there is already a tool called `watch` but I think you already know this.

Comment: Yes but I have to create my own watch :) however your code solve my problem thanks